# Anyone have an e-text of the Doctrina Jacobi in Greek?

Tags: christianity, middle-east, greek, islamic-history

I have been trying to find an e-text of the Doctrina Jacobi in its original language. Does anyone have the Doctrina Jacobi ([The teaching of Jacob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_of_Jacob)) (  text form) in the original Greek.

Comment: Is there a reason that you have tagged this with [islam] and [islamic-history]? While the text seems to mention Islam (as well as Judaism), it seems that the text itself is a Christian one.

Comment: @RobertColumbia the text's claim to fame is being one of the earliest references (if not the earliest reference) to Muhammad

Comment: At least you have most of it at internet archive: https://archive.org/details/patrologiaorient08pariuoft/page/744/mode/2up